# Oracle SQL addition of columns using dates

Tags: oracle10g

i have a table "Bill"

```
   BILLNO   BILL_DATE      AMOUNT

        1 27-SEP-13        100
        2 27-SEP-13        100
        3 27-SEP-13        100
        4 27-SEP-13        100
        5 27-SEP-13        100
        6 27-SEP-13        100
        7 27-SEP-13       1000
        8 27-SEP-13       1000
        9 27-SEP-13        150
       10 27-SEP-13        150
       11 27-SEP-13        150
```

The table definition is:

```
BILLNO     NUMBER(10) 
BILL_DATE  DATE
AMOUNT     NUMBER(10)
```

i want to calculate sum (amount) on distinct (dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select trunc(bill_date), 
       sum(amount)
from bill
group by trunc(bill_date);
```

Comment: that was exactly i need thanks "a horse_with_no_name"